# what is the difference between args and str in java?

Tags: java

When you write

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

And when you write

```
public static void main(String[] str) {

}
```

they seem to do the same thing. Am I wrong? And what is the difference between str and args?

Comment: Variable names don't matter (as long as you refer to the one you're  currently using), and so they're the same

Comment: No functional difference whatsoever.

Comment: it is just convention to use `args` as this is a descriptive name of what the variable holds

Comment: They're different names for the same argument, and names don't affect the method signature, so there's no difference. `args` is the more common convention though.

Comment: Duplicate question found, and question closed. I knew it had to be out there.